# Difference in Declaring array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

What is difference between writing below two?

```
int[] array = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

and

```
int[] array =  {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Comment: There's no difference. It's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: Here you go: [The actual definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html). Read on.

Answer (score 0):

Method - 1: declaration, instantiation and initialization 
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

Method - 2: declaration, explicit instantiation and initialization 
int[] array = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6};

**Prefered when what to use like**
 display(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6});
**and this will not work for Method - 1**
 display({1,2,3,4,5,6});

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between this two in term of execution/compilation.
The only difference is if you find one more readable than the other then use it.